# Web Service saving a string value from a function

Tags: vb.net, string, web-services, function, asmx

I was just wondering if a Web Service can save something i send to it as a string without resetting it everytime i call the WS?

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function sendLCDBrightnessLevel(ByRef command As String) As String
    'This reads a number for the LCD brightness level and store it
    'The phone will call this function every 5 minutes to see what the value is
    'android phone->WS
    Dim lcdLevel As String = ""

    If command <> "READ" Then
        lcdLevel = command
        Return "Stored: " & lcdLevel
    Else
        Return lcdLevel
    End If
End Function
```

Would **lcdLevel** retain the value in **command** if the app just checks it?

Example:

I send it *30* for the **command** and since its not **READ** it stores it in **lcdLevel**. Once the Android phone gets around to the **"every 5 minutes"** check, will it read *30* or will it be nothing?

I'm thinking that i need to move **Dim lcdLevel As String = ""** outside the function since its at the start of the function call each time? Do i just need to place that outside the function in order to keep the value stored or is there something else i also need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Not without some sort of session management. Web Services are stateless just like regular web pages.

Comment: @AdrianGodong thats what i was thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function sendLCDBrightnessLevel(ByRef command As String) As String
    'This reads a number for the LCD brightness level and store it
    'The phone will call this function every 5 minutes to see what the value is
    'android phone->WS
    Dim lcdLevel As String = ""
    Dim path As String = "c:\temp\lcdValue.txt"

    If command <> "READ" Then
        lcdLevel = command
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(path, False, Encoding.UTF8)

        objWriter.WriteLine(lcdLevel)
        objWriter.Close()

        Return "Stored: " & lcdLevel
    Else
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8)

        lcdLevel = objReader.ReadToEnd
        objReader.Close()

        Return lcdLevel
    End If
End Function
```

Guess this is the only way to store a value easily in a WS? 
Seems to work as i needed it too.